# Shape dashed line, dash doesn't work

Tags: android, android-shape

I want to make dashed line using `shape`.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:color="@color/grey_divider"
                android:width="1dip"
                android:dashWidth="5dip"
                android:dashGap="13dip"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

On my device I see this:
[image]
But I need something like this:

[image]

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

Make one xml file in drawable.(e.g. dashed_line.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px"
       android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

And now use this xml file in your layout.

```
android:background="@drawable/dashed_line"
```

Comment: <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_line"
    android:layerType="software" />

Comment: android:layerType="software" - only this line help me, even with my XML. Write as answer pls

Comment: Hi @Artem 
 
android:layerType="software" gives dotted line "hardware" is used for plane line

Comment: software used to stop hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Add this drawable: dash_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:dashGap="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Then use drawable as background:

```
<View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dash_line"
            android:layerType="software" />
```

Don't forget the attribute for low sdk devices

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Detail here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel